# How to replace the dropdown list arrow with my own?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, styling

What would be the easiest method to replace the default arrow of the dropdown list with my own arrow image ?

Comment: I would doubt that you can. Surely it's browser sepcific, probably using a native o/s widget?  In fact, since there isn't an HTML tag for it, how woudl you influence it with CSS?

Comment: oops, looks like @Stephen has found a solution. My apologies.

Comment: @LeonixSolutions Technically, it replaces the `select` element entirely (rather than changing the graphic), while the `select` is hidden away and manipulated via JS controls instead of native controls.

Comment: then I revert to my original comment (and wish I had posted it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only good looking solution I've found is by using jQuery UI and this plugin.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Uniform. It allows you to mask your standard controls with something sexy using JQuery: http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform

You'll be able to replace your dropdown list by using this simple line:

```
$(function(){ $("select").uniform(); });
```

You can also change your radio buttons and checkboxes by using the same method. There is still some downloadable themes available at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 1):

The styling of the default arrow totally depends on th kind of O.S you use.You can check the drop down box in Windows, linux they will take default O.S styling.

The best way to style the arrow is to use jquery plugin like :
http://www.dev4press.com/jgd/dropdown/
http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/463